# the A, the B and the C

Tags: american-english

I have the following sentence in my thesis.

> I employ X excluding the A layer and the B function.

Although I know that I can skip the second 'the', I use it.

But I need to add one more like this.

> I employ X excluding the A layer, the C layer, and the B function.

Or should I write this?

> I employ X excluding the A layer, C layer, and B function.

Comment: I employ X (excluding the A and C layers and the B function).

Comment: Use whichever you are sure will be more clear to your intended audience. Either way please, if you meant literally "I employ X excluding the A layer and the B function" thats one thing but otherwise, why won't half your readers assume those letters are stand-ins and the real substitutes might change everything?